CONSOLE C# ERROR "The gRPC channel URI 'http://xxxxx' could not be parsed"
Mi aplicación de consola va a levantar las API's me esta saliendo este error al compilar


y el connection string?? y que hace esa clase???  todo suena raro.. y si, eso no es una URI valida...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

ya encontre la solución en el archivo .csproj agregar
Exe
net7.0
v4...
